# Why Valki returns stolen card even after the transformation?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Why [Valki](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=503724) returns stolen cards even after the transformation? It is obvious, why Valki returns the stolen cards without the usage of its activated ability. But after becoming a copy of one of the stolen cards Valki loses its text with "... until Valki leaves the battlefield"?

[image: Valki, God of Lies]

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a card references itself by name, it means "this object".

> 201.4. Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.

This means that Valki's first ability refers to the card presently represented by Valki, God of Lies, not one *named* that. It'll still be the same object even if it changes its name or characteristics somehow, such as with its activated ability.

Comment: Ok, that is clear. But the object text is replaced. the text ".. leaves the battlefield" is replaced? The passive ability itself seems to be gone? Can you clarify your answer on that?

Comment: @DenisGladkiy No - this is a delayed trigger being set up, and once it's set up, it doesn't need to actually be in the card's text anymore, the game remembers it's waiting for that card to leave the battlefield before it does something.

Comment: @Andrew Actually, also no - this is 610.3 _"Some one-shot effects cause an object to change zones “until” a specified event occurs. A second one-shot effect is created immediately after the specified event. This second one-shot effect returns the object to its previous zone."_